# Cypress wont wait for a response form API call

Tags: javascript, api, automation, automated-tests, cypress

I have an API written in Flask, with URI

```
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/idpa/isIPv6"
```

what it does is it checks whether the device I am trying to communicate to has network address belonging to IPv6 or not.
Based on the response I am trying to perform further activities,
the cypress test that I have written is

```
it("Website testing",function(){
        cy.request({
            method: 'GET',
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/isIPv6",
            timeout:300000
        }).then(network_result => {
            cy.log(network_result.body)
            if(network_result.body.isIPv6 == false)
            {
               statements
            }
            else
            {
                cy.log("IPv6 device, stopping the test")
                cy.wait(10000)
                expect(true).to.equal(false)
             }
         })
})
```

the API call takes around 90 seconds to return response.

On running the test file, cypress sometimes does not wait from a response, where upon the execution control goes directly to else block wherein it does not log the message or does not wait for 10 seconds, it directly executes the `expect` statement. And when `expect` is commented then the test ends successfully.

I have tried editing the cypress.json file with

> {
> "requestTimeout":300000,
> "responseTimeout":300000 }

But this thing also hasn't worked for me.

How do I make cypress wait for a response ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using Aliases:

```js
it("Website testing",function(){
        cy.request({
            method: 'GET',
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/isIPv6",
            timeout:300000
        }).as("getData");

        cy.wait('@getData'); // <--- wait explicitly for this route to finish
        cy.get("@getData").then(network_result => {
            cy.log(network_result.body)
            if(network_result.body.isIPv6 == false)
            {
               statements
            }
            else
            {
                cy.log("IPv6 device, stopping the test")
                //cy.wait(10000)
                expect(true).to.equal(false)
             }
         })
})
```